# Unable to delete almost empty topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

I am trying to remove the [Introduction to saml-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/saml-2.0/5634/introduction-to-saml-2-0) page, as it barely contains any information, is flagged multiple times with improvement requests and I've started a new, clean, [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/saml-2.0/6938/saml-2-0-introduction) with more concise information and examples around the same topic.

There is no trashcan visible next to the topic, to delete the topic:

[image: Delete button missing]

In the improvement request notification I am seeing a delete button:

[image: delete topic button]

But unfortunately gives the following error when trying to submit the deletion draft for review:

[image: Error when deleting]

Why can't I delete this topic? Does it have something to do with the limited amount of topic existing for the linked tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the introductory topic which is created automatically by the system when a tag's Documentation is created. Since every tag needs an introductory topic, you can't delete it. Introductory topics include tag's versions and get called out specifically in the tag dashboard.

Generally, instead of deleting the intro topic, you'd want to suggest an edit to rollback inappropriate edits. In your particular case, you should suggest an edit moving your examples from the topic you created to the system-created topic. (You might also update the Remarks and Versions section while you are at it.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I was not aware of the 'introductory topic' concept, and was also unable to get this from the error message provided. Maybe this can be updated to reflect the error error...? "Introduction topics cannot be deleted, maybe expand on it instead?". In this case I've just submitted merging of the two topics for review. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick: Good points all around. I'm putting this on our backlog. Fixing the error should be easy, but we also need to make the intro topic more obvious, I think.

Comment: There are definitely improvements possible to the placeholder topic itself. A SO native UI element marking it as a placeholder would make it more clear and not confuse new users thinking they are looking at a poorly written draft of a new topic... For now I've at least documented the functionality and the introductory topic concept itself, [pending review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/98071) :).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx-8/topics) topic should also be delete, it was created automatically. I don't see a way to suggest moving or a rollback or anything at all. Same with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java.util.scanner/topics) one.

Comment: @user1803551: At some point we'll build an automated process to remove Docs tags that haven't been modified. There's no particular hurry, however.

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact: this is actually an issue with improvement requests. As you observed, the trashcan icon isn't shown on introductory topics. The fact that we still showed "delete topic" as a possible handling action for improvement requests was an oversight.

Starting with the next build, the only available option in those cases will be "edit topic".